# Merge data.tables keeping most recent rows or appending new ones

Tags: r, merge, data.table

Suppose I have two data.tables that I want to merge on two variables, but update entries where another column (time) is greater than in the original.  Also, it should be a full join, so if there are new variables in the new data, they should be appended.  What is a good solution for this problem?

Example:

```
## Initial data
dt1 <- data.table(user=c('a', 'a', 'b'), 
                   cell=c(1, 2, 1),
                   expires=as.POSIXct(rep('Jan 25 21:24', 3), format='%b %d %H:%M'))

## New data to update initial
dt2 <- data.table(user=c('a', 'c'), 
                 cell=c(1, 1),
                 expires=as.POSIXct(rep('Jan 25 21:59', 2), format='%b %d %H:%M'))

## Attempt
merge(dt1, dt2, by=c('user', 'cell'), all=TRUE)[
  , expires := pmax(expires.x, expires.y, na.rm=TRUE)][]

## Desired result: user a in cell 1 has been updated, user c has been added
(res <- rbindlist(list(dt2, dt1[2:3,]))[order(user, cell)])
#    user cell             expires
# 1:    a    1 2016-01-25 21:59:00
# 2:    a    2 2016-01-25 21:24:00
# 3:    b    1 2016-01-25 21:24:00
# 4:    c    1 2016-01-25 21:59:00
```

Comment: Is the only difference between your attempt and desired solution the extra columns?

Comment: One option would be `res1 <- dt1[dt2, expires:= pmax(expires, i.expires) , on =c('user', 'cell'), by = .EACHI];res2 <- dt2[dt1, expires:= pmax(expires, i.expires) , on =c('user', 'cell'), by = .EACHI]; unique(rbindlist(list(res1, res2)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it seems like you will need to run and outer join here anyway (which isn't very memory efficient usually), just running `rbind` should be computationally cheaper, then just a simple `order` (which seemingly utilizes `data.tble`s `forder`) wrapped in `data.table`s `unique` method and this looks promising

```
unique(rbind(dt1, dt2)[order(-expires)], by = c("user", "cell"))
#    user cell             expires
# 1:    a    1 2016-01-25 21:59:00
# 2:    c    1 2016-01-25 21:59:00
# 3:    a    2 2016-01-25 21:24:00
# 4:    b    1 2016-01-25 21:24:00
```

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, you're close to the solution and you just have to extend your chain operation as follows:

```
require(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(user=c('a', 'a', 'b'), 
                  cell=c(1, 2, 1),
                  expires=as.POSIXct(rep(Sys.time(), 3)) )
# user cell             expires
# 1:    a    1 2016-01-26 11:19:49
# 2:    a    2 2016-01-26 11:19:49
# 3:    b    1 2016-01-26 11:19:49


## New data to update initial
dt2 <- data.table(user=c('a', 'c'), 
                  cell=c(1, 1),
                  expires=as.POSIXct(rep(Sys.time(), 2)) )
# user cell             expires
# 1:    a    1 2016-01-26 11:20:46
# 2:    c    1 2016-01-26 11:20:46

## Attempt
res_merge = merge(dt1, dt2, by=c('user', 'cell'), all=TRUE)[
  , expires := pmax(expires.x, expires.y, na.rm=TRUE)][, `:=`(expires.x=NULL,expires.y=NULL)][]

# user cell             expires
# 1:    a    1 2016-01-26 11:20:46
# 2:    a    2 2016-01-26 11:19:49
# 3:    b    1 2016-01-26 11:19:49
# 4:    c    1 2016-01-26 11:20:46
```